# Android : How to handle animation of a layout while orientation change?

Tags: android, animation

I added an animation to a linear layout and when animation is running if I change orientation it crashes. I am using .startAnimation(Animation) for running animation of the layout. How to handle animation of an element during orientation change ?

Answer (score 0):

Open your manifest.xml file .change in your activity tab .

```
<activity
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 
            android:name=".testActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
```